# Apollo subscription not working

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-subscriptions

I have a graphql server and I'm attempting to trigger an event whenever the status of an entity is updated. I have a mutation for updating the entity, which uses `graphql-subscriptions` to publish the update for the subscriber to listen to. However, `pubsub.subscribe(EVENT_NAME)` picked up the change, but when I integrate that into the subscription resolver, it doesn't trigger the update.

I've redacted parts of the code not relevant to the issue for brevity.

My resolver:

```
Mutation: {
  updateStatus(_, { id, status, hash }) {
    return repository.updateStatus(id, status, hash);
  }
},
Subscription: {
  updatedStatus: {
    subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator('updatedStatus'),
  }
},
```

My repository:

```
export const updateStatus = async function(id: String, status: String, hash: String) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${baseURL}/article/${id}/status?publish_hash=${hash}`, {
      headers,
      method: 'PATCH',
      body: JSON.stringify({ status })
    });

    const article = await fetchSingleArticle(id, 'XML', headers.channel, false);

    await pubsub.publish('updatedStatus', article);
    return article;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

My schema:

```
type Mutation {
  updateStatus(id: ID!, status: PublishingStatus = PUBLISHING, hash: String): Article
}

type Subscription {
  updatedStatus(id: ID!): Article
}

schema {
  query: Query
  mutation: Mutation
  subscription: Subscription
}
```

To test this, I'm just using graphiql, which is picking up the websocket connection fine.

I've attempted the publish using both `article` (as shown) and `{ updatedStatus: article }`, neither seem to get picked up.

As mentioned previously `pubsub.subscribe('updatedStatus')` does pick up the change. So the issue seems to be related to the Subscription resolver.

I'm going off the following docs: http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-subscriptions/setup.html#setup

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using an out of date graphql package! Updating to the latest version fixed this problem.